# Using Async with MVC4 and Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, async-ctp

I'm watching this lecture http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287 and on 14:08 he says that MVC4 has the Async feature. I have VS2010 with MVC4 beta installed, but doesn't have the Async available. 
After doing some search I understaand that to use Async you need VS11 and what is more important that here https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/vs11/ they tell that Azure doesn't support VS11 projects yet. 
This is very confusing because in the video he does not tell that I need VS11 and I can't tell from the UI if it is VS11.

So my question is there a way how can I TODAY use  Async + MVC4 on Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) that you could install and which enables this feature in VS2010. It stays CTP though. The feature will be part of the .NET 4.5 framework and available with VS11.

Comment: The VS2010 CTP is just an add-on to the C# 4.0 compiler. So it spits .NET 4.0 assemblies which are compatible with Azure. On the other hand VS11 spits .NET 4.5 which is not compatible and yet supported on Azure.

Comment: Thanks! At least I don't have to install VS11 yet.

Comment: I have installed the CTP, but it still doesn't resolve the async keyword. Am I missing something, maybe a reference?

Comment: You need to add reference to the `AsynchCtpLibrary.dll` assembly which should normally be located in the `Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the new MVC 4 and .Net 4.5 features on Azure, please go to the Azure UserVoice site and vote for this feature: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2598170-iis8-and-asp-net-4-5-support-in-azure-platform